# Disk space used by small numbers in a BigInt column

Tags: sql-server, storage

Say I have a column that is defined to be a `BigInt`.  The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) say that a BigInt uses 8 bytes of memory.

If I then go store 1000 rows with the value `21` in that column, is it going to take up 8,000 bytes?  Or does SQL Server optimize the storage to use less space?

Note: I asked this question in part because I know that SQL Server can adjust the size it uses on disk for a `varchar` based on the actual data size.

Comment: *Each* value uses up 8 bytes because each value is a `bigint`. This is why the documentation you linked to states *"To save space in the database, use the smallest data type that can reliably contain all possible values."* If you have 1,000 rows, you have 1,000 `bigint` values, each 8 bytes in size; 8 * 1000 = 8000.

Comment: On your new comment on `varchar`, that is an abbreviation of `varying character`. The integer based data types aren't variable length values; they are stored more like a `char` (which is a fixed width value). The variable length data types (I am ignoring deprecated data types) all have `var` in their name: `varchar`, `nvarchar` and `varbinary`.

Comment: Look at row  compression if you want that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/row-compression-implementation#how-row-compression-affects-storage

Answer (score 0):

Datatype beginning by the letters VAR is really stored as variable length but use 2 bytes more to store the lenght of the data. So a VARCHAR(1) will use 2 or 3 bytes. Two if NULL or empty string, three if filled.
All other datatype are not variable length and use exactly the number of bytes the doc says, without the 2 bytes more of the variables ones.

So having tinyint of smallint or int inside a bigint will always use 8 bytes in the page, except if some compression is enabled :

- SPARSE compression : discard NULLs entries
- DATA_COMPRESSION (row mode) : only the used bytes